# plotly.io.write_image() doesn't create svg file

Tags: python, svg, plotly

```html
<svg class="main-svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="700" height="500" style="" viewBox="0 0 700 500"><rect x="0" y="0" width="700" height="500" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255); fill-opacity: 1;"/><defs id="defs-2e509b"><g class="clips"><clipPath id="clip2e509bxyplot" class="plotclip"><rect width="540" height="320"/></clipPath><clipPath class="axesclip" id="clip2e509bx"><rect x="80" y="0" width="540" height="500"/></clipPath><clipPath class="axesclip" id="clip2e509by"><rect x="0" y="100" width="700" height="320"/></clipPath><clipPath class="axesclip" id="clip2e509bxy"><rect x="80" y="100" width="540" height="320"/></clipPath></g><g class="gradients"/></defs><g class="bglayer"><rect class="bg" x="80" y="100" width="540" height="320" style="fill: rgb(229, 236, 246); fill-opacity: 1; stroke-width: 0;"/></g><g class="layer-below"><g class="imagelayer"/><g class="shapelayer"/></g><g class="cartesianlayer"><g class="subplot xy"><g class="layer-subplot"><g class="shapelayer"/><g class="imagelayer"/></g><g class="gridlayer"><g class="x"><path class="xgrid crisp" transform="translate(234.29,0)" d="M0,100v320" style="stroke: rgb(255, 255, 255); stroke-opacity: 1; stroke-width: 1px;"/><path class="xgrid crisp" transform="translate(311.43,0)" d="M0,100v320" style="stroke: rgb(255, 255, 255); stroke-opacity: 1; stroke-width: 1px;"/><path class="xgrid crisp" transform="translate(388.57,0)" d="M0,100v320" style="stroke: rgb(255, 255, 255); stroke-opacity: 1; stroke-width: 1px;"/><path class="xgrid crisp" transform="translate(465.71,0)" d="M0,100v320" style="stroke: rgb(255, 255, 255); stroke-opacity: 1; stroke-width: 1px;"/><path class="xgrid crisp" transform="translate(542.86,0)" d="M0,100v320" style="stroke: rgb(255, 255, 255); stroke-opacity: 1; stroke-width: 1px;"/></g><g class="y"><path class="ygrid crisp" transform="translate(0,292)" d="M80,0h540" style="stroke: rgb(255, 255, 255); stroke-opacity: 1; stroke-width: 1px;"/><path class="ygrid crisp" transform="translate(0,228)" d="M80,0h540" style="stroke: rgb(255, 255, 255); stroke-opacity: 1; stroke-width: 1px;"/><path class="ygrid crisp" transform="translate(0,164)" d="M80,0h540" style="stroke: rgb(255, 255, 255); stroke-opacity: 1; stroke-width: 1px;"/></g></g><g class="zerolinelayer"><path class="xzl zl crisp" transform="translate(157.14,0)" d="M0,100v320" style="stroke: rgb(255, 255, 255); stroke-opacity: 1; stroke-width: 2px;"/><path class="yzl zl crisp" transform="translate(0,356)" d="M80,0h540" style="stroke: rgb(255, 255, 255); stroke-opacity: 1; stroke-width: 2px;"/></g><path class="xlines-below"/><path class="ylines-below"/><g class="overlines-below"/><g class="xaxislayer-below"/><g class="yaxislayer-below"/><g class="overaxes-below"/><g class="plot" transform="translate(80, 100)" clip-path="url('#clip2e509bxyplot')"/><g class="overplot"/><path class="xlines-above crisp" d="M0,0" style="fill: none;"/><path class="ylines-above crisp" d="M0,0" style="fill: none;"/><g class="overlines-above"/><g class="xaxislayer-above"><g class="xtick"><text text-anchor="middle" x="0" y="433" transform="translate(80,0)" style="font-family: 'Open Sans', verdana, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; fill: rgb(42, 63, 95); fill-opacity: 1; white-space: pre;">−1</text></g><g class="xtick"><text text-anchor="middle" x="0" y="433" transform="translate(157.14,0)" style="font-family: 'Open Sans', verdana, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; fill: rgb(42, 63, 95); fill-opacity: 1; white-space: pre;">0</text></g><g class="xtick"><text text-anchor="middle" x="0" y="433" transform="translate(234.29,0)" style="font-family: 'Open Sans', verdana, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; fill: rgb(42, 63, 95); fill-opacity: 1; white-space: pre;">1</text></g><g class="xtick"><text text-anchor="middle" x="0" y="433" transform="translate(311.43,0)" style="font-family: 'Open Sans', verdana, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; fill: rgb(42, 63, 95); fill-opacity: 1; white-space: pre;">2</text></g><g class="xtick"><text text-anchor="middle" x="0" y="433" transform="translate(388.57,0)" style="font-family: 'Open Sans', verdana, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; fill: rgb(42, 63, 95); fill-opacity: 1; white-space: pre;">3</text></g><g class="xtick"><text text-anchor="middle" x="0" y="433" transform="translate(465.71,0)" style="font-family: 'Open Sans', verdana, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; fill: rgb(42, 63, 95); fill-opacity: 1; white-space: pre;">4</text></g><g class="xtick"><text text-anchor="middle" x="0" y="433" transform="translate(542.86,0)" style="font-family: 'Open Sans', verdana, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; fill: rgb(42, 63, 95); fill-opacity: 1; white-space: pre;">5</text></g><g class="xtick"><text text-anchor="middle" x="0" y="433" transform="translate(620,0)" style="font-family: 'Open Sans', verdana, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; fill: rgb(42, 63, 95); fill-opacity: 1; white-space: pre;">6</text></g></g><g class="yaxislayer-above"><g class="ytick"><text text-anchor="end" x="79" y="4.199999999999999" transform="translate(0,420)" style="font-family: 'Open Sans', verdana, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; fill: rgb(42, 63, 95); fill-opacity: 1; white-space: pre;">−1</text></g><g class="ytick"><text text-anchor="end" x="79" y="4.199999999999999" transform="translate(0,356)" style="font-family: 'Open Sans', verdana, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; fill: rgb(42, 63, 95); fill-opacity: 1; white-space: pre;">0</text></g><g class="ytick"><text text-anchor="end" x="79" y="4.199999999999999" transform="translate(0,292)" style="font-family: 'Open Sans', verdana, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; fill: rgb(42, 63, 95); fill-opacity: 1; white-space: pre;">1</text></g><g class="ytick"><text text-anchor="end" x="79" y="4.199999999999999" transform="translate(0,228)" style="font-family: 'Open Sans', verdana, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; fill: rgb(42, 63, 95); fill-opacity: 1; white-space: pre;">2</text></g><g class="ytick"><text text-anchor="end" x="79" y="4.199999999999999" transform="translate(0,164)" style="font-family: 'Open Sans', verdana, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; fill: rgb(42, 63, 95); fill-opacity: 1; white-space: pre;">3</text></g><g class="ytick"><text text-anchor="end" x="79" y="4.199999999999999" transform="translate(0,100)" style="font-family: 'Open Sans', verdana, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; fill: rgb(42, 63, 95); fill-opacity: 1; white-space: pre;">4</text></g></g><g class="overaxes-above"/></g></g><g class="polarlayer"/><g class="ternarylayer"/><g class="geolayer"/><g class="funnelarealayer"/><g class="pielayer"/><g class="treemaplayer"/><g class="sunburstlayer"/><g class="glimages"/><defs id="topdefs-2e509b"><g class="clips"/></defs><g class="layer-above"><g class="imagelayer"/><g class="shapelayer"/></g><g class="infolayer"><g class="g-gtitle"/><g class="g-xtitle"/><g class="g-ytitle"/></g></svg>
```

I want to save a plotly figure as a svg-file. My code looks like this:

```
import os
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.io as pio

if not os.path.exists(r"S:\FC\FCD\06_Datenbanken\FCD Dashboard\Budget-Ausschöpfung"):
    os.mkdir(r"S:\FC\FCD\06_Datenbanken\FCD Dashboard\Budget-Ausschöpfung")
    
fig = go.Figure()

pio.write_image(fig, r"S:\FC\FCD\06_Datenbanken\FCD Dashboard\Budget-Ausschöpfung/fig.svg", format = "svg")
```

The code runs without error but the saved pictures name is "fig.svg" but the datatype is Chrome HTML Document.

When I just use:

```
pio.write_image(fig, r"S:\FC\FCD\06_Datenbanken\FCD Dashboard\Budget-Ausschöpfung/fig.svg")
```

the output file is also a Chrome HTML Document.

And when I use:

```
pio.write_image(fig, r"S:\FC\FCD\06_Datenbanken\FCD Dashboard\Budget-Ausschöpfung/fig", format ="svg")
```

The type of my outputfile ist just "data" or "data file" (just "Datei" in german, but I don't know what that should mean?) and it can't even be openend.

I am using plotly 4.8.1, I have read, that I should use plotly 4.9 but unfortunately, conda is not able to install it and always hangs itself when I try to install it. Other packages are no problem to install...

Edit: I included a screenshot showing my fig.svg Chrome HTML Document in the Chrome broswer and the settings of fig.svg

[image: Picture]

Comment: a) I went into the dircetory where you can see the file name, last change date, data type and memory size. There I can see the file "fig.svg" and type says Chrome HTML Document. 
b) The HTML Documents can be opened with Chrome and shows an empty figure (as expected here). But I want to include the plots in a powerpoint presentation, that doesn't work with HTML files

Comment: What do you mean by providing content? sharing the file? If yes how? Sorry I am quite new to stackoverflow

Comment: I added a screenshot. Was that what you mean? I couldn't find a way to share fig.svg

Comment: Ah thanks. Now I shared the html file. It says " class="main-svg" ", does that mean it is svg? But I can't copy it into my powerpoint presentation...

Comment: Yes, that's an SVG file.

Comment: Oh cool, thank you! But do you know why it has such a strange name and can't be openedin powerpoint? When I copy the file and try to insert it into powerpoint i can only see the Chrome logo and the filename written below it

Comment: You've set Chrome as the default tool to open SVG files so that's what Chrome does. I don't know why it doesn't work in Powerpoint.